# Errors when trying to pass args in clojure using clj-http

Tags: clojure

hopefully this is something simple for the more experienced out there. I am using clj-http and trying to pass the command line arg int it (to take a URL). I am an absolute Clojure beginer but I have managed to pass the args through to a ptintln which works.

```
(ns foo.core
  (:require [clj-http.client :as client]))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (def url (str args))
  (println url)
  (def resp (client/get url))
  (def headers (:headers resp))
  (def server (headers "server"))
  (println server))
```

Error message

```
Ants-MacBook-Pro:target ant$ lein run "http://www.bbc.com"
("http://www.bbc.com")
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ("http://www.bbc.com")
```

This works

```
(def resp (client/get "http://www.bbc.com"))
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it's a list instead of a string?

Comment: I've tried letting Clojure default it to hatever it wants, a string as per the example and even tried as-url (which didn't seem to work at all at the point of casting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`args` is a list, which means that calling `str` on it returns the representation of the list, complete with parentheses and inner quotes, as you can see in your error trace:

```
(println (str '("http://www.bbc.com")))
;; prints ("http://www.bbc.com")
```

Of course, URLs don't start with parentheses and quotes, which is why the JVM tells you your URL is malformed.

What you really want to pass to `get` is not the string representation of your argument list, but your first argument:

```
(let [url (first args)] 
  (client/get url)) ;; Should work!
```

In addition, you should never use `def` calls within functions -- they create or rebind vars at the toplevel of your namespace, which don't want.

What you should be using instead is `let` forms, which create local variables (like `url` in my example). For more information on `let`, look at http://clojure.org/special_forms.

I'd probably structure your code like so:

```
(defn -main
  [& args]
  (let [url (first args)
        resp (client/get url)
        server (get-in resp [:headers "server"])]
    (println url)
    (println server)))
```